# Is it possible to make one view DependentUpon another view in Visual Studio solution explorer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have custom extended Razor view engine to handle localized versions of views and partial views so I have a lot of views like `Index.cshtml` (default one), `Index.en-US.cshtml`, `Index.ru-RU.cshtml`, `Index.uk-UA.cshtml` etc. I have them displayed in my solution explorer like this:

[image]

which is not very nice, because I'll have a lot of such views in the future and it will be the mess. So I tried to edit `.csproj` file manually:

```
<Content Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Views\Home\Index.en-US.cshtml">
   <DependentUpon>Views\Home\Index.cshtml</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="Views\Home\Index.ru-RU.cshtml">
   <DependentUpon>Views\Home\Index.cshtml</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="Views\Home\Index.uk-UA.cshtml">
   <DependentUpon>Views\Home\Index.cshtml</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

to achieve effect like with Web.config files:

[image]

But it didn't help. File tree structure stays the same as on the first screen shot. There's free [File Nesting](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c) extension for visual studio which can possibly make this happen but this effect will be visible only for me (since I am the one owning the extension) but not for my teammates, it will force them to install the extension too. ***Is it possible to achieve this without installing the extension and without editing .csproj file manually (it would save some time).***